# Resources file management in c++

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I am new to c++ i am from JAVA.

How the resource files are managed in c++?

In java we use a separate source folder "resources" and use the same package name.

```
src
 com.example.test
   Example.java
resources
 com.example.test
   config.xml
```

and we can get the config.xml in Example.java using `getClass().getResource("config.png"));`

How can do the same or what is the way to achieve this situation.

Comment: There are no "resources" in C++.

Comment: It all depends. Some systems, like Visual Studio on Windows, have similar systems. Other environments have no concept of "resources", and you have to handle it manually in the code. So if you want to be portable across environments and platforms you have to deal with resource management yourself.

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg There's also the option of using a portable library for this. E.g. Qt has its own resource system.

Comment: @PeterWood Linux and mac

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support resources. But you can use some framework to achieve similar functionality. Use Qt, for example: [Qt resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single resource file to store all the resources you need for the project together. [Here](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/C%3aCustom_Resource_Files) is a good template that you could either use as is or change to suit your needs. I have personally used a modified version of this for one of my own recent projects. For C++, you could update the library calls to use C++ STL, or just use the C library. Also another template [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/tutorials/formatdat).

Comment: Personally, I don't mind having my BMPs and WAVs "flapping naked in the wind". I rather like it that way. :-)

Comment: Using a resource file, you can also handle compression and decompression and discourage users from tinkering with needed resources. You can also have resources that aren't files